# Как перезаписать в файле TXT значение с 0 на 1?

Tags: php

Всем привет. Есть файл TXT, нужно переписать только одно значение между запятыми. В данном случае это $array[3] в определенной строке.
Но вот заменить (т.е записать). Никак не получается. Беда с файлами, мне тут уже помогали с этим.

Пример, что нужно заменить. Находит строку и в ней значение [3].

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Вот код, который находит строку и подстроку. Как что нужно добавить, что он перезаписал array[3] на единицу '1'.

```
$utm = 'НОМЕР СТРОКИ';

foreach ($arrayData as $value) {
    $arrayUserData = explode(',', $value);
    if ($arrayUserData[0] === $utm) {
        $array = $arrayUserData;
    }
}


echo 'Индекс: ' . $array[0] . '<br>';
echo 'Имя: ' . $array[1] . '<br>';
echo 'Имя2: ' . $array[2] . '<br>';
echo 'Состояние: ' . $array[3] . '<br>';
```

Comment: Не оперируйте строками - придётся перезаписывать чуть не весь файл. Открывайте его как прямого доступа и меняйте байты по смещению.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$needle = "qwe,";              // что ищем
$len = mb_strlen($needle);     // и его длина
$lines = file("path/to/file"); // где ищем

// перебираем строки
foreach ($lines as $idx => $line) {
    // если нашлось
    if (mb_substr($line, 0, $len-1) == $needle ) {
       $row = explode(',', $line);         // разделили
       $row[3] = 1;                        // заменилии
       $lines[$idx] = implode(',', $row);  // собрали, записали
       break;                              // три-четрые, закончили
    }
}
file_put_contents(implode("\n", $lines);   // сохранили
```

как-то так видимо, плюс минус на синтаксис

Comment: Спасибо большое!